# Transform XML using XSL - What structure choose?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two `XSL` file for transform my xml.

**File1.xsl :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"
            media-type="text/xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="File">
        <File>

            <Purchaser>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Customer/LastName"/>
                </Name>
            </Purchaser>

            <vehicles>
                <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
                    <vehicle>
                        <vehicleColor>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                        </vehicleColor>
                        <vehicleModel>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Model"/>
                        </vehicleModel>
                        <vehicleYear>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
                        </vehicleYear>
                        <vehicleSpeed>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Speed"/>
                        </vehicleSpeed>
                        <Towns>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Towns/Town">
                                <Town>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </Town>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Towns>
                    </vehicle>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </vehicles>

        </File>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**File2.xsl :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"
            media-type="text/xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="File">
        <File>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Customer"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Cars"/>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer">
        <Purchaser>
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
            </Name>
        </Purchaser>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Cars">
        <vehicles>
            <xsl:for-each select="Car">
                <vehicle>
                    <vehicleColor>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                    </vehicleColor>
                    <vehicleModel>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Model"/>
                    </vehicleModel>
                    <vehicleYear>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
                    </vehicleYear>
                    <vehicleSpeed>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Speed"/>
                    </vehicleSpeed>
                    <Towns>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Towns/Town">
                            <Town>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </Town>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Towns>
                </vehicle>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </vehicles>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Question n°1 : The two file do the same thing but I don't know what structure choose. What is the "best" structure ?

Question n°2 : In my File1 in `<Name><xsl:value-of select="Customer/LastName"/></Name>` am I forced to put the full path ? How to put only "LastName" in `select` attribute ?

Comment: 1) Usually having more (shorter) templates is a better option, in terms of reuse, readability. You can also rewrite your second stylesheet with more recursive templates and get rid of the other two for-each. If both are working for you it makes no difference. 2) You can't put only "LastName" in that attribute, because it's a path *relative* to the template's current node "File", and its xpath is "File/Customer/LastName" (the other template has "Customer" as current node, so then you can use only "LastName".

Comment: Your first question calls for opinions and as such is off-topic for SO. -- Re your second question: `Customer/LastName` is **not** the "full path"; it's the relative path from the current node.

Comment: Thank for your response. I think the file1 is then best adapted